# Resultado de pesquisa de ActionResult não retorna todos os resultados para View PagedList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, mvc

Observei que em minha aplicação antes de adicionar a **View** o **Paged List** ele recebia todos o itens retornados da **ActionResult** responsável pelas pesquisas, então a partir da implementação do **Paged List** não obtenho todos os resultados de minha **controller**.

Em resumo a ActionResult obtêm todos os resultados da pesquisas mas a View não recebe todos os resultados da pesquisas para ser mais específico, não recebe os valores vindo da **var pesquisa** da cláusula **x.CategoriaEmpresa.Any(c => c.Categoria.Nome.Contains(empresa))** da pesquisa abaixo

**Instrução da Pesquisa abaixo**

```
var pesquisa = db.Empresa.Where(x => x.Cidade.Contains(cidade) &&
                                (x.Nome.Contains(empresa)
                                || x.CategoriaEmpresa.Any(c => c.Categoria.Nome.Contains(empresa))))
                                .ToList();
```

**ActionResult Resultado**

```
public ActionResult Resultado(string empresa, string cidade, int? pagina)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(empresa) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(cidade))
    {
        return Redirect("Index");
    }

    int pageSize = 4;
    int pageNumber = (pagina ?? 1);

    ViewBag.cidade = new SelectList(db.Empresa.Select(a => a.Cidade).Distinct());
    ViewBag.empresaPesquisada = empresa;
    ViewBag.cidadePesquisada = cidade;

    var pesquisa = db.Empresa.Where(x => x.Cidade.Contains(cidade) &&
                        (x.Nome.Contains(empresa)
                        || x.CategoriaEmpresa.Any(c => c.Categoria.Nome.Contains(empresa))))
                        .ToList();

    return View(pesquisa.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

**View Resultado - Configurada com Paged List**

```
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@model PagedList.IPagedList<SigaLista.Areas.Admin.Models.Empresa>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Resultado da Pesquisa";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="container ajuste-rodape">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h4>Sua pesquisa retornou @Model.Count @(Model.Count > 1 ?  "Empresas" : "Empresa") </h4>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {                
                var destaque = false;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Logomarca))
                {
                    destaque = true;
                }                
                <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-left media-middle">

                        @if (destaque)
                        {
                            <img src="@Url.Content(item.Logomarca)" alt="Image" style="width: 120px; height: auto;" />
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <div class="sem-imagem"></div>
                        }

                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading">@Html.ActionLink(item.Nome, "Detalhes", new { id = item.Id })</h4>
                        <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Telefone)</p>
                        <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Endereco), @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Numero)</p>
                        <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cidade) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Estado) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cep)</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>    
        @Html.Partial("_PartialSideBar")
    </div>

    @*@if(Model.PageCount > 4)*@@* O ERRO ESTA AQUI *@
    @if(Model.TotalItemCount > 4)@* AQUI FUNCIONA PERFEITAMENTE *@
    {
        @:Página @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) de @Model.PageCount
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Resultado", new { empresa = ViewBag.empresaPesquisada, cidade = ViewBag.cidadePesquisada, pagina = page }))
    }

</div>
```

Comment: Tá fazendo errado. No lugar do ToList tem que ser o ToPagedList

Comment: @VirgilioNovic fiz conforme você disse, alias já havia testado isto e não obtive sucesso, mas fiz o retorno fica assim e não funcionou: 

return View(db.Empresa.Where(x => x.Cidade.Contains(cidade) &&
                                (x.Nome.Contains(empresa) || x.Descricao.Contains(empresa)
                                || x.CategoriaEmpresa.Any(c => c.Categoria.Nome.Contains(empresa)))).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));

Não funcionou.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic esta dando o seguinte erro: System.NotSupportedException: 'The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.'

Comment: Não sei o que andou fazendo, mas vc está fazendo errado estou no celular daqui a pouco eu vejo

Comment: Faltou OrderBy!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic encontrei o erro, na qual não me retornava todos os resultados de minha pesquisa, e foi erro meu na escolha de uma das funcionalidades do PagedList que faz com que não apareça o paginador na View, então sempre funcionou a comunicação entre minha a ActionResult e a View e assim compartilho a solução que é esta, modifique o item dentro da condicional if ficando assim @if(Model.PageCount > 4) para @if(Model.TotalItemCount > 4) e assim funcionará perfeitamente.

Comment: Coloque isso como resposta!